# prevent nested columns inheriting padding - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this class:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    float:left;
        padding-left:14px;
    padding-right:14px;
}
```

But don't want any columns in nested grids to inherit this padding, how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: not able to understand can please elaborate more.?

Answer (score 0):

you can select whatever is nested inside columns with:

```
[class*="col-"] > *{
   /* whatever you want to reset*/
}
```